# mod_rewrite based on cookie value

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, cookies

I have a multilingual website and I need change the URL based on a cookie value.

For example, I have `$_COOKIE["lang"] = "en"` and I want to change the URL to either `www.mydomain.com/en/rest/of/the/url` or `en.mydomain.com/rest/of/the/url`.

How can I do this?

Comment: What server-side language are you using? PHP? AFAIK, mod_rewrite can't read a cookie.

Comment: I use PHP. So is there any option how to do it by PHP?

Comment: Nice, it *can* be done with mod_rewrite - see Maxim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use any kind of redirect available to you. In vanilla php you can user [header()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php).

mod_rewrite is a webserver-based directive, it works well before your php script gets a chance to kick in, and it most definitely cannot touch cookies.

Update: You CAN, in fact, use cookies from mod_rewrite (practical link [here](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/151897-mod-rewrite-based-on-cookie-value-regexp-in-mod-rewrite/), official docs [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond)).
I do not, however, recommend it as can and will ruin code debugging - few people will think of looking in .htaccess for cookie-based redirects.

Comment: +1 but you're slightly incorrect: you can read the cookie string in mod_rewrite directives. In OP's case, a simple regex would do the trick.